# Evaluate the following integral

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm asked to evaluate $$\frac{d}{ds} \int_{0}^s e^{st^2} dt$$

The solution to this problem says the following:

$$\frac{d}{ds} \int_{0}^s e^{st^2} dt = e^{ss^2}+\int_{0}^s \frac{\partial}{\partial s} e^{st^2} dt$$

Could someone explain why this is the case?

The solution says that it uses the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

Comment: You may also wish to look up the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**: Use [differentiation under the integral sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign)
$$    \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}s} \left (\int_{a(s)}^{b(s)}f(s,t)\,\mathrm{d}t \right) = f(s,b(s))\cdot b'(s) - f(s,a(s))\cdot a'(s) + \int_{a(s)}^{b(s)} \frac{\partial}{\partial s}f(s,t)\; \mathrm{d}t$$
with $a(s)=0,\,b(s)=s$ and $f(s,t)=e^{st^2}$.